# Are any[Param] and Param(anyInt) equivalent while stubbing in Scala Spec2?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, spec2

I'm having a strange behaviour while stubbing method that takes case classes as parameters.

I'm still trying to understand why, but in one case I'm getting a

```
You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
```

When stubbing like this

```
simpleTrait.anotherMethod(any[Param]) returns "Mock String"
```

and I have to change it like this

```
simpleTrait.anotherMethod(Param(anyInt)) returns "Mock String"
```

Where

```
case class Param(val: Int)
```

and

```
trait SimpleTrait {
  def anotherMethod(someParam: Param): String
}
```

Both the behaviour seems equivalent, though.

Any Ideas?

Comment: how is `simpleTrait` defined?